# Replace all integers until a certain character

Tags: substitute, replace

I am making a table which has chemical formulas in the first column so I need the integers as subscripts to use it in a LaTex file.

I want to transform `CH4 &` to `CH$_4$ &`, `C2H5 &` to `C$_2$H$_5$ &` and so on. How do I select all integers before the occurrence of `&` in a line and add the suffix and a prefix to it?

Comment: Do you want to operate on all the integers before the *first* occurrence of an ampersand, or all the integers that come before *any* ampersand. Or is there guaranteed only to be one ampersand on the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are only interested in replacing the numbers before the *first* ampersand on each line, one fairly crude way to do it is to first split the lines on the first ampersand, then perform the substitutions, and then rejoin the lines:

```
:g/\&/norm! f&i^M
:g/^[^&]/s/\d\+/$_\0$/g
:g/^&/norm! kJ
```

In the first line, the `^M` is a literal carriage return which you can enter by pressing: <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. A more copy-and-pastable version of that line is as follows:

```
:execute "g/\&/norm! f&i\<CR>"
```

If, on the other hand, you want to replace any integers that come before *any* ampersand, or if each line is guaranteed only to have one ampersand, then a one-liner is possible:

```
%s/\d\+\ze.*&/$_\0$/g
```

Comment: I understood the substitution. Could you please explain what the first line means?

Comment: Yes, sorry, bit short on explanation. I’ll fill in tomorrow if I get a chance, but the first and third lines of the first solution are both using `:global` to run a `:normal` command on each line that matches a regexp. `:normal` just acts as though you pressed the specified keys, so the first line acts as though you visited every line that contains an ampersand and then pressed `f&i<CR>` i.e. jump to the ampersand and insert a newline.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular problem, the better solution is to instead use the LaTeX package [mhchem](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) for typesetting the formulas. A good solution is similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}

% This is only used for pretty rules (\toprule, etc)
\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\zzz#1\relax{\ce{#1}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\zzz}l<{\relax}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Fl}
  \toprule
  Formula & More \\
  \midrule
  CH4 & 1 \\
  C2H5 & 2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For more info, see [this tex.stackexchange.com question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332042/using-mhchem-with-array) and the [mhchem documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf).